# Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012, sccm

I am using SCCM 2016, Windows Server 2012. I am using the code below to move a collection to another folder. I get the error message `Move-CMObject : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null.`

I've researched the error via Google but I still can't understand how 'InputObject' is null. I have seen other PS script formatted the same way and it is a working script. I'd like to know how to fix this and move the collection to another folder.

```
$sitecode = "123"
$colltomove = "JJJ00287"
$destcollfolder = '$($sitecode):\DeviceCollection\Test Operational' 

$collID = Get-CMCollection -Name $colltomove
Move-CMObject -InputObject $collID -FolderPath $destcollfolder
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is tested and proven to work. You have to put " (double-quotes) at line 3 around `"$($sitecode):\DeviceCollection\Test Operational"` and `"$destcollfolder"` at line 9. Also at line 9 you need to use `Get-CMDeviceCollection -CollectionId $collection |` in addition to the `Move-CMObject -FolderPath "$destcollfolder"`

```
$sitecode = "123"
$colltomove = "JJJ00287"
$destcollfolder = "$($sitecode):\DeviceCollection\Test Operational"

$collID = Get-CMCollection -Name $colltomove
#Move-CMObject -InputObject $collID -FolderPath $destcollfolder

Get-CMDeviceCollection -CollectionId $collection | Move-CMObject -FolderPath "$destcollfolder"
```